# Storage allocation to const variables

Tags: c++, constants, storage

I am reading a book which mentions this

> If the compiler knows every use of the const, it need not allocate
>   space to hold it. For example:
>
> 1. `const int c1=1;`
> 2. `const int c3=my_f(3);`
> 3. `extern const int c4;`
>
> Given that values of c3 and c4 are not known as compile time, storage
>   must be allocated for c3 and c4.

I didn't understand any of this. My doubts are:

What does it mean by holding here? Wouldn't it still need to store everything in memory?
For c1, wont we have any storage allocation?

Please clear my doubts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c1` is different from the other two constants in that it is initialized with a *literal value*. This lets compiler put that value everywhere the constant is used, like this:

```
int x = z + c1;
```

can be replaced by

```
int x = z + 1;
```

This means that the compiler does not need to allocate space and store `1` in it.

`c3` and `c4` are different: one is calculated using a function, and the other one is supplied from a different compilation unit. This means that the compiler can no longer perform the substitution the way it could with `c1`: the values of the `c3` and `c4` are not known to the compiler. Therefore the compiler generates code for

```
int x = z + c4;
```

in the same way as if `c4` were a variable stored in some place in memory. Since in this case `c4` is an external constant, the linker will resolve its location, and fill in the information the compiler is missing (namely, the address of `c4`) to make the program complete and ready to run.

Comment: Thanks for answering but that does that mean whenever a variable defined as a const and initialized with a literal, it acts like a macro and wherever in the program is used compiler justs replaces the variable with value?

Comment: @Leoheart The compiler is *allowed* to do that replacement, and most compilers do it. But as far as I know, the compilers do not have to "inline" declared constants: the standard allows them to do either way. Moreover, you are allowed to take an address of a declared constant, in which case the compiler places it in memory in addition to inlining it at the places where it is used.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Apart from all this, I also read that, Compiler holds the definition in its Symbol Table, for such const variable.
How Symbol table would help in it, if Compiler does - "
int x = z + c1;

can be replaced by

int x = z + 1;"

as you said above. ?

Answer (score 2):

Const has 2 uses - replacement for macros (constant expressions) and also immutable data.

This statement:

```
const int c1=1;
```

Is essentially a type-safe version of this:

```
#define c1 1
```

Such that this code:

```
int foo = c1;
```

Could simply be compiled as:

```
int foo = 1;
```

Which is more efficient.

On the other hand, this:

```
const int c3=my_f(3);
```

Is being used as an immutable c3. It likely exists in memory, but you can't modify it. It essentially is a safer version of `int c3=my_f(3);`.

To illustrate this:

```
int a1[c1];
int a2[c3];
```

a1 is valid, as the compiler can deduce a1 to be a constant expression. a2 is not, as while c3 is const, it may not be known at compile-time.

C++11 adds the `constexpr` keyword which is similar to `const`, although is more strict than `const`. Only `c1` and `c2` could be `constexpr`. `c3` could also be, although it would require that `my_f` is too.

Answer (score 1):

As an Integral Constant Expression, the compiler has every right to use constant folding to remove it from the program. This is only not true if you take it's address. In addition, a modern optimizing compiler can employ LTO, inlining and constant folding to do the same with c3 and c4, if it's possible.

If you do not take the address of a variable, the compiler has no obligation to allocate it if it can generate code with equivalent outcomes, under the as-if rule.

Edit: Constant folding is where the compiler evaluates expressions at compile-time instead of run-time. For example, you can legally do `int x[3 + 4];` where `3 + 4` is evaluated at compile-time. Some examples, specifically those involving ICEs, are Standard mandated, but the implementation can perform more if possible. LTO is Link Time Optimization, which is where the compiler performs optimizations across translation units when they are linked together.

This means that the compiler can inline the body of `my_f`, and then (depending on the body) constant fold it out to make `c3` a constant expression, and then constant fold it into wherever it's used and not allocate it. For `c4`, LTO might yield the value of `c4` as a constant expression, in which case it can be constant folded and removed as well.

In C++11 there are `constexpr` functions which allow much more to be done in this region.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not able to understand your answer too. what is constant folding and LTO?

Comment: One last question: does that mean whenever a variable defined as a const and initialized with a literal, it acts like a macro and wherever in the program is used compiler justs replaces the variable with value?

Comment: @Leoheart: No, not at all. Macros are textual substitution, constant folding is semantic substitution. Secondly, the compiler can only do that for some situations and some types.